# Preserving permissions while zipping

Tags: zip

How can I preserve permissions while compressing a folder using `zip`?

I know how to preserve symlinks using `--symlinks` is there a similar option for permissions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

info-zip (the program you probably are using) can save/restore permissions for *Unix*-like systems.

It is mentioned for **directories** in the [manual page](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html):

> Dates, times and permissions of stored directories are not restored except under Unix. (On Windows NT and successors, timestamps are now restored.)

File-permissions for read/write/execute are saved/restored.  But a quick check shows (zip 3.0) that setuid/setgid permissions are not preserved.

The feature is not optional; zip/unzip simply do this when they are able.

On other systems, the ability to save/restore permissions is less complete.  For example, on Windows the ZIP file uses the permission settings from the **`%temp%`** folder.

Further reading:

- [Is ZIP archive capable of storing permissions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/585817/is-zip-archive-capable-of-storing-permissions)
- [Can i store unix permissions in a zip file (built with apache ant)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633488/can-i-store-unix-permissions-in-a-zip-file-built-with-apache-ant)

Comment: Excellent answer! I did not know that about info-zip.

Comment: I tried to download infozip, but win10 report it is virus contained.

Comment: You could get the binaries from various places (not all good).  It's been widely redistributed.

Comment: But how do I set the execute file mode for a .sh file on Windows so when its extracted on Linux it works?

Answer (score 19):

Info-Zip 3.0 SUPPORTS preserving files/dirs UNIX permissions and UID/GID ownership data. `zip` stores it by default but you need to use `unzip` in an special way to restore them:

- `unzip` must be used with the `-X` flag.
- `unzip` must run as `root` to set the files/dirs UID/GID. If you run it as a normal user then the UID will be always the one of the current user and the GID will be restored ONLY IF the current user belongs to that group.

Example:

```
# zip -v | head -2 | tail -1
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.

# unzip -v | head -1
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.

# touch file1
# mkdir dir1
# chmod 000 file1
# chown 1111 dir1
# ls -ld file1 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 1111 root 40 mar 28 20:12 dir1
---------- 1 root root  0 mar 28 20:12 file1

# zip files.zip file1 dir1
  adding: file1 (stored 0%)
  adding: dir1/ (stored 0%)

# unzip -X files.zip -d extracted
Archive:  files.zip
 extracting: extracted/file1         
   creating: extracted/dir1/

# ls -l extracted
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 1111 root 40 mar 28 20:12 dir1
---------- 1 root root  0 mar 28 20:12 file1
```

Note: you can also use `unzip` with the `-K` flag to also restore SUID/SGID/Sticky bits.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you can't! `zip` does not preserve file permissions.

Read more about this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/603068/unzipping-file-whilst-getting-correct-permissions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735297/maintain-file-and-folder-permissions-inside-archives).

If you need to preserve permissions, please consider using `tar` with the `--preserve-permissions` switch instead.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/940477/109788 .  I can view permissions with `zip -Z <file>` .

Comment: @BinoyBabu Yeah, I read that post. I find it to be somewhat ambigous: ”If you didn't make the ZIP file yourself, your only chance is to set the correct the permissions after unzipping”. The keyword here being **after**.